# Two-dimensional sinc function

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to write a function for a 2D sinc function: `y = (sin(x1)*sin(x2)) / (x1*x2)` uniformly on the input range [-10, 10] for both x1 and x2. My approach looks like:

```
import numpy as np
import math 

x1 = np.linspace(-10, 10, 50)
x2 = np.linspace(-10, 10, 50)

array = []

for i in range(len(x1,x2)):
    array.append(math.sin(x1,x2[i]))
    i += 1
print("array : ", array)
```

But I receive this error: `len() takes exactly one argument (2 given)`.

Comment: It's not very clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: What exactly is unclear about the error message?

Comment: What's the purpose of `len(x1,x2)`?  And why are you passing 2 variables (one an array) to `math.sin`?  DId you even take time to read the `math.sin` docs?  When you encounter errors like this, take time to read the docs, and do some testing in an interactive session.

Answer (score 2):

There might a way to use [np.sinc()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sinc.html) directly but I'm not sure offhand how to generate the proper input matrix. Here's a more brute force approach that gets you where (I think) you want to be:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sinc2d = np.zeros((50, 50))
for x, x1 in enumerate(np.linspace(-10, 10, 50)):
     for y, x2 in enumerate(np.linspace(-10, 10, 50)):
         sinc2d[x,y] = np.sin(x1) * np.sin(x2) / (x1*x2)

# equivalently (thanks @Kelly Bundy):
x1 = np.linspace(-10, 10, 50)
x2 = np.linspace(-10, 10, 50)
sinc2d = np.outer(np.sin(x1), np.sin(x2)) / np.outer(x1, x2)

plt.imshow(sinc2d)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As the error describes, the len() function only takes one input.
On line 9, you have iterate from `len(x1)` to `len(x2)`:
`for i in range(len(x1),len(x2)):`